# Программа корректна только для пустой пачки параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer

Насколько я понимаю, следующая программа не должна компилироваться в соответствии [со стандартом](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.3), однако последние версии `gcc`, `clang` и `MSVC` компилируют её без ошибок. Я что-то неправильно понимаю или это дефекты компиляторов?

> **12.7 Name resolution [temp.res]**
>
> **8** … The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> (8.3) every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack

```
template<typename... Args>
struct A {
    A(const Args&... args) : x(0, args...) {}

    int x;
};

int main() {
    A<> x;
}
```

Comment: А в связи с чем конкретно она не должна компилироваться по-вашему? Ну вызвали дефотный конструктор, ну инициализировали `x` `0`. Если напишите `A<int> x{0};` - то тогда она не компилируется, все нормально

Comment: Стандарт стандарту рознь. Последняя версия С++ вроде 17. Поэтому и результат разный. Я встречал ситуации, когда параметры шаблона выводились из параметров вызова функции. Надо смотреть какой стандарт используется по умолчанию.

Comment: @VTT в связи с тем, что шаблон с переменным числом параметров является валидным только при пустой пачке параметров, или это не так?

Comment: Для variadic template ноль - вполне валидное кол-во параметров.

Comment: *"шаблон с переменным числом параметров является валидным только при пустой пачке параметров"* что? зачем тогда эти параметы нужны, если он по-вашему валидный только если пустой? Может вы имели ввиду "валидным при непустой пачке"?

Comment: @älёxölüt да, я это знаю, но тут вопрос про конкретный пункт по ссылке, либо я неверно его интерпретировал

Comment: @VTT параметры для примера приведены, чтобы протестить этот пункт стандарта

Comment: @Adokenai попробовал на 11, 14, 17 - везде компилируется

Comment: @travor я только сейчас слона заметил: x(0, args...). Ничего не смущает в инициализации?

Comment: Несложно написать такой шаблон с переменным количеством параметров, который будет валиден только со строго определенным количеством параметров. Не понятно, что вас так смущает с вариантом с 0 параметров.

Comment: @VTT меня смущает, что такой вариант запрещен стандартом, судя по ссылке, что я привёл. Вы переходили по ней? Я правильно понял смысл пункта?

Comment: @travor, так стандарт не обязывает это проверять, а только допускает такую проверку...

Comment: @Fat-Zer то есть для `ill-formed` программы компилятор не обязан выдавать ошибку компиляции?

Comment: Хм, перечитав начало, нашел там такие строки *"The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:"* *"every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack"* и в меня закрались смутные сомнения...

Comment: @VTT так я на этот пункт и ссылаюсь, надо было цитату привести сразу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required

и

> gcc, clang и MSVC компилируют её без ошибок

Ошибка - это и есть diagnostic. В этом случае стандарт разрешает ее не печатать.

<sub>(Любая ошибка - это diagnostic, но не любой diagnostic - это ошибка. Подробнее ниже.)</sub>

---

Вообще, стандарт *не запрещает* компиляторам компилировать ill-formed программы.

Единственное требование: Компилятор обязан выдать diagnostic - то есть указать пользователю на ошибку (если нет приписки 'no diagnostic required', конечно) - с помощью ошибки компиляции или предупреждения.

Если компилятор продолжил компиляцию несмотря на ошибку, то полученная программа может вести себя как угодно - стандарт не делает по этому поводу никаких гарантий.

Comment: То есть "выдать `diagnostic`" = ошибка компиляции, или может быть `warning` или ещё что-то?

Comment: @travor Любое сообщение.

Comment: Только вот непонятно, с чего это вдруг если шаблон с переменным количеством параметров может иметь валидные специализации только со, скажем, 3 параметрами - это нормально. А когда только с 0 параметров - *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.

Comment: нашёл [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918009/multiple-pack-expansions-inside-class-with-fixed-number-of-template-arguments) на `enSO`, там уже отказывается компилироваться

Comment: @VTT, вот DR: [1231](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3236.html#1231), там причина не объясняется, но ясно видно кто зачинщик. Можно его спросить.